# PHP Code for "Required/Input Email Should Contain '@' and at least one dot. '.'"

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a PHP file where password and email has to have a requirement for their files. Requirements I am doing in a separate document.

So far for my password I have this set up in register.php
->

```
<div class="tRow>
                <div class="tCell"><label for="txtpassword">Password:</label></div>
                <div class="tCell">
                <input type="password" id="txtpassword" name="Password"/>
                </div>
            </div><!-- END OF THIS SELECTION -->`
```

When user clicks Submit Button
-> `div class="tRow">
                    <div class="tCell"><input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Sumbit" onclick="CheckLength('txtpassword')" /></div>
                </div><!--END OF THIS SELECTION-->`

I am currently doing the same for email.

`<div class="tRow>
                    <div class="tCell"><label for="user_email">E-mail:</label></div>
                    <div class="tCell">
                    <input type="text" id="user_email" name="E-mail"/>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- END OF THIS SELECTION -->`

Any suggestions on how to add the requirement for the email?

Comment: Are you looking for a php and/or javascript solution? you have js here. The post is both unclear and too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another event to the onclick - something like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Sumbit" onclick="CheckLength('txtpassword'); checkemail('user_email')" />
```

Then you would have to write a javascript function to handle the email validation, something like:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
    }
```

(From [How to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript))

Comment: Seems like I had something different when i was doing the validation for password. Thank you for showing me this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to check the email using what languages ​​provide us natively.

First, HTML5 introduces a **new input type**: `email`
Check the documentation: [MDN Web Docs | Email input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email)

Invalid input example: `é@ç`
Valid input example : `-@_` , `e@n`

```
<input type="email" id="user_email" name="E-mail" />"
```

Secondly, with PHP, you can use **validate filters** to check if the value submitted is an email
Check the documentation: [PHP Docs | Validate filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

```
<?php
$email = "john.doe@example.com";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo("$email is a valid email address");
} else {
  echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
?>
```

If you want to use JavaScript to check your value, read this response on another Stackoverflow question:
[How to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/6024780)

Hoping it helps you ;)

Comment: This really helps! Thank you!